# Interesting double Limit

Tags: limits

While computing The Fourier transform of a function tending to become a simple blip I came across
$$\underset{w\to 0}{\lim_{T\to 0}} \left[ \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{wT}{2}\right)}{\omega^2 T}\right] $$

I think we can split this into 
$$
\underset{w\to 0}{\lim_{T\to 0}}\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{wT}{2}\right)}{wT}\right]\cdot 
\underset{w\to 0}{\lim_{T\to 0}}\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{wT}{2}\right)}{w}\right]$$ and say that the limit of the first term tends to 1, but what about the second term?
Thank you!

Comment: Id it $\sin((wT/2)^2)$ or $(\sin (wT/2))^2$?

Comment: @julien i interpret it this way, john please check if I did it right

Comment: Yes you interpreted it the right way.

Comment: why is this interesting in your eyes?

Answer (score 1):

you can use that for small values of $w$ and $T$ 
$$\sin\left(\frac{wT}{2}\right)\approxeq \frac{wT}{2w} $$
So the limit should be $0$

Answer (score 0):

I'll just sequentially use limit. First in $w$ and then in $T$:
$\lim_{T \to 0 , w\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(wT/2)}{w^2T}=\lim_{T \to 0 }\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sin(wT/2)}{wT}\frac{\sin(wT/2)}{w}=\lim_{T \to 0 }\frac{1}{2}\frac{T}{2}=0$

Comment: why can you look at first the limit of $w \to 0$ and afterward the other? Some limits depend on that

Comment: @DominicMichaelis because in this case double limit can be reduced to iterated limit. It depends on the function under limit sign.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis well, for "double limit Vs iterated limit" you can refer here (http://books.google.ru/books?id=gD4RHZeYcbMC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=double+limit+and+iterated+limit&source=bl&ots=uJXCQ3YnrI&sig=kAgHRVDJ0ZCrEXz4-a1zfJKQNWk&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=KR9PUbCbJ-Xl4QTD6oG4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=double%20limit%20and%20iterated%20limit&f=false): 
Operator Theory and Ill-Posed Problems by L. Ya: Savelev , M. M. Lavrentev, Hardcover, 696 Pages, Published 2006 by Brill Academic Publishers (Chapter 3, page 185).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Double limits may heavily depend on order:
$$a_{m,n}:=\frac{m}{m+n}:\quad\lim_n\lim_ma_{mn}=1\quad\lim_m\lim_na_{mn}=0\quad\lim_{n=m^2}a_{mn}=\infty$$

But it can be even more abstruse as for:
$$\Delta a_{mn}=a_{mn}-a_{nm}:\quad\lim_m\Delta a_{mn}=1\quad\lim_m\lim_n\Delta a_{mn}=1\quad\lim_{n=m^2}a_{mn}\notin\mathbb{R}$$

So you certainly have to be careful about that!!

**Application**

Many really bad mistakes may be done in physics this way...

*(Narrow Potential, Thermodynamic Limit, Bose-Einstein Condensation)*